# where should my .csv file be for the package datatool to read it?

Tags: datatool

I apologize for the newbie question. I just started using LaTeX. Where should my .csv be located if I want the package datatool to read it?

I am so sorry for posting such as question.

Comment: same places an input tex file could be, eg same folder as your document